# Spinning numbers on viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a spin function which makes the number rotates every 4 seconds. Now I need to start that function once when the numbers are on viewport, so when on viewport start function only once, I don't mean to rotate the numbers only once, just the function to start only once, and when numbers are not in the viewport anymore then do nothing and so on.

My problem comes when I play scrolling while numbers are visible, because that makes the function spin, to fire many times.

I kinda understand what is going on here, but just can't manage it in javascript, everytime I scroll, the scrolling listener fire multiple times so it also fires multiple times the .each() and also the spin function? If someone can explain what is the problem and how to solve it, would be nice.

If you have a fiddle to share would be nice.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dse5rba/2/)

```
  var slots = $('.numbers').find('.slot');

if( slots.length ){

    var isScrolling;
  
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function ( event ) {
  
    // Clear our timeout throughout the scroll
    window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );
    
    // Set a timeout to run after scrolling ends
    isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {
    
        slots.each(function(){
      
        let slotHeight = $(this).height();
        let animateTo = (-slotHeight + 21);
        
        if( isElementInViewport( $(this)[0] ) ){
        
            if( ! $(this).is(":animated") ){
            spin($(this), animateTo);
          }
          else{
            return false;
          }
        
        }
      
      });
    
    }, 200);
  
  });

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: so you want to spin it once per getting into viewport or once overall after getting to the viewport? if the second one, just remove the listener after animating

Comment: @FlashThunder The spin function I have, makes the number rotates every 4 seconds which is ok, that's the purpose. But I need to start that function once the numbers are on viewport, so when on viewport start function only once (I don't mean to rotate the numbers only once, just the function to start only once), and when numbers are not in the viewport anymore then do nothing and so on. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing makes sense, because the scroll event triggers many, many times while scrolling (not just once when the scroll starts or ends or something like that).

If you'd like your behavior to be triggered less often, there are several options available to you. You could keep the scroll event listener and use a debounce or a throttle to reduce the number of triggers. Or you could listen to a different even altogether.

In your case, it sounds like you would like to trigger an action once an element comes into view, and then only once. For that, you could still run your scroll handler, but check if the element in question is visible, and then run the rest of your logic. Once that's done, you could de-register your event handler (scroll handlers are potentially expensive because they run so often).

Comment: Thanks for helping, I edited my question to try to make it more explainable but to summarize. The spin function I have, makes the number rotates every 4 seconds which is ok, that's the purpose. But I need to start that function once the numbers are on viewport, so when on viewport start function only once (I don't mean to rotate the numbers only once, just the function to start only once), and when numbers are not in the viewport anymore then do nothing and so on. Hope you understand

Comment: @DanielSoublett Well, it looks like currently you reschedule the animation every time the user scrolls. You need some flag to tell whether you've already started the animation. Then when the user scrolls and that flag is true, you don't start the animation again, UNLESS the element scrolls out of view, then you stop the animation and set the flag to false again. Also I think you need to use setInterval, not setTimeout, since you want the animation to repeat.